# Query without value before certain date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, exists

I'm being trained in database management and this is my first post ever, so I apologize if I don't follow a standard procedure in posting. I have searched and just can't find an answer.

In PostgreSQL, I'm trying to find all new customer orders in 2014. But some customers may have been added in 2013 or 2012, but didn't make their order until 2014.  So I'm trying to query where Customers do not have an order before 1/1/2014, or in other words, their first order is after 12/31/2013.

I know this only shows new customers added in 2014, I just need to somehow grab the ones added before that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_name, COUNT (cust_name)
FROM cohead
JOIN custinfo
ON cust_id=cohead_cust_id
WHERE cust_dateadded >='1/1/2014' AND cust_dateadded <='12/31/2014'
AND cohead_orderdate >='1/1/2014' AND cohead_orderdate <='12/31/2014'
GROUP BY cust_name
ORDER BY cust_name
```

Comment: Your query does not disclose where each column originates from. Please provide table definitions (what you get with `\d tbl` in psql), or at least table-qualify columns in the query. Use table aliases to keep it readable. And *always* declare your version of Postgres please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted query, it would be pointless to add `DISTINCT`, since you already have `GROUP  BY cust_name`.

But I suggest a completely different approach that's probably faster.
This retrieves all customers who placed their first order in 2014 - no matter when they were added to the `custinfo` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   custinfo cu
WHERE  EXISTS (  -- with order in 2014
   SELECT 1 FROM cohead
   WHERE  cohead_cust_id = cu.cust_id  -- guessing
   AND    cohead_orderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (  -- but no order before 2014
   SELECT 1 FROM cohead
   WHERE  cohead_cust_id = cu.cust_id
   AND    cohead_orderdate < '2014-01-01'  -- assuming a date column
   );
```

For big tables be sure to have indexes to support this query.

Comment: The EXISTS and NOT EXISTS were what I was looking for but couldn't find any language for. I've only been really doing this for about 2 weeks so far. I just changed it to reflect our tables and the columns and counts I needed and then filtered out 4/27/2012 which was a mass migration date for a lot of customers into the database. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this only returned 1 value when I added the COUNT function. I need to be able to count all of the orders they made in 2014. I just got a big column full of 1's.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I joined the cohead table because it was pulling cust_name values that didn't repeat in the custinfo table. Now it's joining all the same names that appear on the orders in cohead so it's counting each order. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: @MichaelWilkey: Your question was a bit vague in several respects. Precise answers for precise questions ...

Comment: Sorry, Like I said, first time poster. Wasn't sure if it was proper to give a long post with all the minutiae of the situation. But you gave me exactly what I needed to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelWilkey: As short as possible, as long as necessary, that's the way to go. :)